# Por que quando incluo o meu cabeçalho .h, a implementação .c não é incluída também?

Tags: c, struct, header, include

Eu tenho três arquivos, `produtos.h`, `produtos.c` e `main.c`. `produtos.h` está localizada na pasta "headers", `produtos.c` está localizada em "sources" e a `main.c` está na mesma pasta que "headers" e "sources", algo assim:

```
pasta
\_headers
| \_produtos.h
\_sources
| \_produtos.c
\_main.c
```

#### main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "headers/produtos.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
     struct produto p;
     p.id = 123;

     printf("Id: %d\n", p.id);

     return 0;
}
```

#### produtos.h:

```
#ifndef PRODUTOS_H
#define PRODUTOS_H

struct produto;

#endif
```

#### produtos.c:

```
#include "../headers/produtos.h"

struct produto {
    char nome[100];
};
```

Ao compilar, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> ```
> main.c: In function 'main':
> main.c:6:20: error: storage size of 'p' isn't known
>    struct produto p;
>                    ^
> ```

Ao que meus testes indicam, o compilador não consegue receber a implementação da `struct` produto, ou seja, ele não consegue receber `produtos.c`, apenas `produtos.h`, qual o meu erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, não faz pelo mesmo motivo que se você quiser digitar `da` e aperta o `d`, o `a` não vai sozinho, afinal teria que adivinhar se você quer aquilo ou não. Mas aí tem outro problema

`sruct` é só declaração, não existe implementação de `struct` então este código C não faz sentido, faça assim no *header*:

```
struct produto {
    char nome[100];
};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Product.c).

E está resolvido.

Comment: Isso resolve, sim, mas o problema continuará se ao invés de eu declarar uma struct, eu declarar uma função. Não posso colocar toda a implementação de uma função em meu cabeçalho.

Comment: Mas você coloca o cabeçalho da função no cabeçalho... não?

Comment: Implementação não precisa ser incluída, então não tem problema.